# How to select and print certain values that are common in dictionary and a list?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

For example:

`cars={'bmw':'sedan','mg':'suv','audi':'sedan'}`
`color=['bmw','audi','bentley']`
And what I wanna do here is to check, if the user enters a string for example,"bmw"
the code checks if its in the list or not and then it goes to the cars dictionary and shows the
output only for bmw as in 'bmw':'sedan'.
So how ca I search for a string in both, I know how to search for strings in dictionary but Idk about how to do that in lists?
for item in color:

```
    if "bmw" in color:
        print "Key found"
        break
    else:
        print "No keys found"
```

But it's juts not working..
Please suggest some code of how to search a string in dictionary and a list?
Also, If I want to add more specifications in a list about a certain thing like we do in Dictionary, can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
cars = {'bmw': 'sedan', 'mg': 'suv', 'audi': 'sedan'}
color = ['bmw', 'audi', 'bentley']

needle = 'bmw'
if needle in color and needle in cars:
    print(cars[needle])
    # sedan
```

Or using `all(...)`:

```
if all(needle in collection for collection in [color, cars]):
    print(cars[needle])
```

Or using `set(...)` with an intersection:

```
if needle in set(cars).intersection(set(color)):
    print(cars[needle])
```

Side question: why are you still using `Python2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
color = ['bmw', 'audi', 'bentley']
cars = {'bmw': "sedan", 'mg': "suv", 'audi': 'sedan'}

# get the user input
user_input = input("Please enter a car")

# checks if user_input exists in color list
if user_input in color:
    # checks if user_input exists in cars dictionary keys
    if user_input in cars:
        print("Color: {}, Car: {}".format(user_input, cars[user_input]))
    else:
        print("{} is not in `cars` dictionary".format(user_input))
else:
    print("{} is not in color list".format(user_input))
```